# How to repeat fetching data from a restful api until the body of the data has different status?

Tags: node.js, loops, fetch, skyscanner

I'm building a an application to retrieve data from SkyScanner (with RapidApi).
Basically  i have to "open session" with the API and then get a Session Key to pull the results. - That's not a problem.

When I get results, i need to check if the result body(not the headers) has a Status with "UpdatesPending". If so - I need to send these result to the clients side, but keep pulling the results with another request to the API, until i get a result with "UpdatesComplete".

Would love a little help here.

I've tried to do an if statement, but it doesn't seem solve it..
i'm using Node.js and the request-promise lib.

```
  rp(options)
.then(response => {
  let index = response.headers.location.lastIndexOf("/");
  console.log(index);
  let sessionKey = response.headers.location.slice(index + 1);
  console.log(sessionKey);

  return sessionKey;
})
.then(sessionKey => {
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/${sessionKey}`,
    qs: { pageIndex: "0", pageSize: "10", sortType: "price", stops: stops },
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host":
        "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": `${RapidapiKey}`
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  };

  let status;
  console.log("first status", status);

  rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      status = JSON.parse(response.body).Status;
      res.status(200).write(response.body);
      if (status !== "UpdatesComplete") {
        rp(options)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response.body).Status);
            status = JSON.parse(response.body).Status;
            res.status(200).write(response.body);
            return response;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });

        console.log("inside if status", status);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have to repeat with some condition, you usually go for recursion. Here you haven't put the code to repeat indefinitely unless the condition is met. You have just called it three times. Please try the below code :

```
rp(options)
.then(handleResponse)
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

function handleResponse(response) {

  let index = response.headers.location.lastIndexOf("/");
  let sessionKey = response.headers.location.slice(index + 1);

  let options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/${sessionKey}`,
      qs: { pageIndex: "0", pageSize: "10", sortType: "price", stops: stops },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host":
            "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": `${RapidapiKey}`
      },
      resolveWithFullResponse: true
  };

  status = JSON.parse(response.body).Status;
  res.status(200).write(response.body);

  if (status !== "UpdatesComplete") {
    return rp(options).then(handleResponse);
  } else {
    return response;
  }
}
```

There might be some syntax error, try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you! i'll try it and let you know.